# Odd Number Detector on FPGA

Tags: verilog, fpga

Implement a circuit that illuminates an LED when an odd number of the eight slide switches are set to “1”.

This is the project that I am trying. Only one solution came to my mind without using libraries (I don't know libraries yet). And it is assigning the led to all switch combinations.

Any idea how to optimize the code with/without using IEEE library?

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module challenge1(

    input [7:0] sw,
    
    output [1:0] led

    );
    
    assign led[0] = ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    ( ~sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) | 
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) | 
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] & ~sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] & ~sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] & ~sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] &  sw[0] ) |
                    (  sw[7] &  sw[6] &  sw[5] &  sw[4] &  sw[3] &  sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) ;
                    
endmodule
```

Comment: We don't see any code to optimize.

Comment: @mkrieger1 well, it is just all possibilites of switches that are open by an odd number. Like ' ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] & ~sw[2] &  sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) | ( ~sw[7] & ~sw[6] & ~sw[5] & ~sw[4] & ~sw[3] &  sw[2] & ~sw[1] & ~sw[0] ) '.

Comment: If you had to build the actual electrical circuit by hand using logic gates and wires, how would you do it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I would try to make it more budget, more efficient.

Comment: @Mikef Done, sorry.

Comment: I meant which logic gates would you connect to the switches and how would you connect the gates to each other. I think you didn't understand what I mean. Long story short, you need a series of XOR gates. The code can be written as a single expression using Verilog's unary XOR operator. Research the term "parity".

Comment: @mkrieger1 Can you give example on my code please. I don't know how XOR gate will work in this situation.

Comment: Here's an example: `^sw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there are no IEEE libraries to assist in coding this if you want to use Verilog or SystemVerilog. Verilog and SystemVerilog are IEEE standards, Verilog is IEEE 1364-2005, SystemVerilog is IEEE 1800-2017.

Here are two methods using Verilog, which are concise relative to the posted code.
Method 1 was provided by @mkrieger1 in the post comments, and is obviously the most concise.  The related concept of parity is worth researching and understanding if you don't know what it is and how it is used.

Read down the code to see Method 2 using a for loop.

```
module challenge1(
    input  [7:0]  sw,
    output [1:0] led
);
  
  reg [3:0] ones_count = 0;
  wire led_0;
  
  // Method 1, xor reduction, AKA even parity
  assign led_0 = ^sw;  
  
  // Method 2, loop over the vector, count the ones
  always @(*) begin
    ones_count = 0;
    for(integer i = 0; i < 7 ; i++)
      if(sw[i] == 1'b1)
        ones_count = ones_count + 1;
      else
        ones_count = ones_count;
  end
  //
  assign led[0] = ones_count[0];
  assign led[1] = 1'b0;
  
endmodule
```

A testbench

```
module challenge1_tb();
  
  reg [7:0] sw;
  reg  [1:0] led;
  integer i;
  
  initial begin
    $monitor("sw = %b, dut.ones_count = %0d, led[0] = %b, dut.led_0 =%b",sw,dut.ones_count,led[0],dut.led_0);
    for(i = 0; i < 8 ; i++) begin
      sw = i;
      #1;
    end
  end
  
  challenge1 dut(
    .sw(sw),
    .led(led)
  );
  
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); 
    $dumpvars;
  end
  
endmodule
```

Produces

```
sw = 00000000, dut.ones_count = 0, led[0] = 0, dut.led_0 =0
sw = 00000001, dut.ones_count = 1, led[0] = 1, dut.led_0 =1
sw = 00000010, dut.ones_count = 1, led[0] = 1, dut.led_0 =1
sw = 00000011, dut.ones_count = 2, led[0] = 0, dut.led_0 =0
sw = 00000100, dut.ones_count = 1, led[0] = 1, dut.led_0 =1
sw = 00000101, dut.ones_count = 2, led[0] = 0, dut.led_0 =0
sw = 00000110, dut.ones_count = 2, led[0] = 0, dut.led_0 =0
sw = 00000111, dut.ones_count = 3, led[0] = 1, dut.led_0 =1
```

If you are able to use SystemVerilog, then the method `$countones()`  can
be used. The use is similar to above, except that the for loop is replaced with `ones_count = $countones(sw);`

Yet another method is to use SystemVerilog's `foreach([<vector>])` statement which is a little nicer replacement for the Verilog `for()` loop.